# Resize images programmatically

Tags: support

For editing purposes, is there a way to resize the images on this website without saving them to your computer, resize them an upload them again?

I've played with some x and y coordinates, but with no luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can now append a s m l to the image URL before the jpg and get a scaled version, but this scaling seems to degrade the quality quite a bit. [Same for making them 200px wide.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/pixelpalooza-requesting-a-feature-to-normalize-sizing-of-portrait-ios-screen-i)

[image: 0: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdFnM.jpg]
[image: s: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdFnMs.jpg]
[image: m: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdFnMm.jpg]
[image: l: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdFnM.jpg]

Yes - I believe changing the embed from `![]` to `<img>` and specifying size x and y works to keep the original image intact yet display a smaller version. I have asked for this to be automated, but it doesn't appear to be getting many up votes. (it's a long question - not so sharp - perhaps it's time to edit it down and ask on the main meta site)

[Pixelpalooza - Requesting a feature to normalize sizing of portrait iOS screen images by default (not just for landscape images)](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884)

So in the mean time, you can edit a post and place `<img ... width="300" />` and use the [strict subset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) of html that is allowed. You can always summon this list from the blue help icon when editing.

[image: HTML editing help]

Comment: Thanks! But you should drop the `px` in the `img` tag, only then it will work :)

Comment: Yup!! That's the best way to do it! Good answer @bmike!